# How to determine if the frame is IDR frame in IPP?

Tags: encoding, h.264, video-encoding, intel-ipp

In my application, I'm trying to use the IPP H.264 Encoder. I've set the encoder options so that every I frame were an IDR frame:

```c
UMC::H264EncoderParams params = new UMC::H264EncoderParams;
// Here set some other useful parameters, and then set IDR interval.
// If it takes the n value then each n-th I frame is encoded as IDR.
params->key_frame_controls.idr_interval = 1;
```

Usually all the generated I-frames are IDR, but sometimes IPP generates I-frames that aren't IDR. It seems that it happens when a great scene changes have been made.

I need to detect IDR frames and differ them from all other frames (including these I-frames that are not IDR). Are there some means in IPP to solve this task? Or it can only be done manually?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe some research into RTSP 'recovery points' will assist you.

http://forum.doom9.org/archive/index.php/t-147533.html